# Setting Instance of MULTIPLE LAYERS using "mapLayersByName" in QGIS Python Scripting?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm currently using "mapLayersByName" successfully to set one active layer at a time as follows...

```
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('My_Layer')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
```

---

Can an instance of multiple layers be set using the "mapLayersByName" method?

I have tried...

```
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('My_First_Layer', 'My_Second_Layer')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
```

As you can see my end goal in this case would be to set the layers within that instance of MULTIPLE layers (vl) as the active layers using the "iface.setActiveLayer()" method.  I notice this method is not plural (i.e. not "setActiveLayers()").  Significant?

Comment: y que otro metodo me permitiria seleccionar una capa por nombre o como podria terminar la instancia registro para en otro metodo volver a instanciar y buscar una capa diferente translated: > and that another method would allow me to select a layer by name or
> how the registration instance could end up in another method to
> re-instantiate and search for a different layer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't.  `mapLayersByName` returns a list of layers matching a single name (you can have many layers with the same name)

`setActiveLayer` takes a single active layer because there is only one active layer at a time in QGIS.